# Zend Framework autoloader in Doctrine 2 repositories

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I use Zend Framework and Doctrine 2 in my project. Everything works fine except, that autoloader doesn't load Zend classes from Doctrine repositories.

Here is my bootstrap part for Zend autoloader:

```
/**
 * Register namespace Default_
 * @return Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
 */
protected function _initAutoload() {
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Default_',
        'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
    ));
    return $autoloader;
}
```

Here is my bootstrap part for Doctrine initialization:

```
/**
 * Initialize Doctrine
 * @return Doctrine_Manager
 */
public function _initDoctrine() {
    // include and register Doctrine's class loader
    require_once('Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php');
    $classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader(
        'Doctrine', 
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/'
    );
    $classLoader->register();

    $classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader(
        'Repositories',
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Model'
    );
    $classLoader->register();

    // create the Doctrine configuration
    $config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

    // setting the cache ( to ArrayCache. Take a look at
    // the Doctrine manual for different options ! )
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

    // choosing the driver for our database schema
    // we'll use annotations
    $driver = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Model'
    );
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

    // set the proxy dir and set some options
    $config->setProxyDir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Model/Proxies');
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Model\Proxies');

    // now create the entity manager and use the connection
    // settings we defined in our application.ini
    $connectionSettings = $this->getOption('doctrine');
    $conn = array(
        'driver'    => $connectionSettings['conn']['driv'],
        'user'      => $connectionSettings['conn']['user'],
        'password'  => $connectionSettings['conn']['pass'],
        'dbname'    => $connectionSettings['conn']['dbname'],
        'host'      => $connectionSettings['conn']['host']
    );
    $entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

    // push the entity manager into our registry for later use
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $registry->entitymanager = $entityManager;

    return $entityManager;
}
```

How could i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your _initAutoload is completely unnecessary.
Just add

```
autoloadernamespaces[]  = Default
autoloadernamespaces[]  = Doctrine
```

to your application.ini

Answer (score 1):

I agree that _initAutoload() shouldn't be necessary, but i suspect you'll need this in application.ini:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Doctrine"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Model"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just starting you project I will advice to use zf2 (beta5 last beta folowing: http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog/entry/Zend-Framework-2-0-0beta5-Released) 
This is tutorial which I was using for my project zf2 + doctrine 2 
 http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/